# Make each distinct value of a column a new column and count in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a similar question like the one here: [distinct values as new columns & count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707359/distinct-values-as-new-columns-count)

But instead of having only 3 values (in the case above: drivers), I have about 1 million, so I cannot list all of them in my code. How can I do that in SQLite?

So I kind of want something like the code below to be repeated for i= 1 to length(DISTINCT(driver)):

```
    SELECT model
    , COUNT(model) as drives
    , SUM(distance) as distance
    , SUM(CASE WHEN driver=DISTINCT(driver)[i] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DISTINCT(driver)[i]
    FROM new_table
    GROUP BY model;
```

Comment: So you want to have one million columns?

Comment: Yes (I have far more observations). I need that step to set up a recommender system using a boolean utility matrix.

Comment: Well, then [you're out of luck](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_column). But why columns? Couldn't this be rows? Or is this a sparse matrix, where it would be better to return one row with each entry's coordinates?

Comment: @CL. Thank you for the hint. Unfortunately no, I have a dataset with far more than 1 million customers where each observation corresponds to one trip (travel data), so my goal is to make the hotels of the trip indicator variables (resulting in a very sparse matrix) and set up a recommender system.
Can you maybe tell me how I would have to process for a smaller number of values (a subset of my dataset), let's say 100? So kind of, what is the generalization of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707359/distinct-values-as-new-columns-count ?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has no mechanism for dynamic SQL. You have to read the list of all possible drivers from the database, and construct the query with a separate SUM(CASE...) column for each value in your program.

But a large number of columns is inefficient, and when it becomes larger than 2000, it will not work anyway.
It might be a better idea to return each matrix entry individually:

```
SELECT model,
       driver,
       COUNT(*) AS drives_for_this_model_and_driver
FROM new_table
GROUP BY model, driver
ORDER BY model, driver;
```